# Tor functor,deleted last term,exactness

Tags: category-theory, exact-sequence, derived-functors

Let have a setting like [this](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~znorwood/partiii/files/commalgnotes2apage.pdf) on page 28. I have some questions on the deletion of the last term $M\otimes N$. We loose by this isomorphism Tor$_0^R(M,N)\cong M\otimes_R N$. The second is why the deleted tensored sequence is exact *at* the last arrow $\to P_0\otimes N\to 0$? Finally, why did we at all erase the last term $M\otimes_R N$ in front of $0$?

Comment: It says that deleting the term $M \otimes N$, we can get a chain complex. So  we don't have that it is exact at $P_0 \otimes N$. After deleting the last term, we can define the $Ext$ or $Tor$ functor, I think. You can see it in homological algebra.

Comment: Ok,nice explanation. But without deleting we would get shifted Tor by one index. Why do we care about the last term at all?Is it only because of this shift in Tor$_i$ by one?

Comment: I remember I have seen at some place that it defines $Tor$ without deleting the last term. To this quesion, I don't know any other purpose. Maybe you can pose a question to ask about it.